# Returning a function with with the parameters of a callback function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, callback, arrow-functions

Consider this function:

```
export const catchAsync = (handler) => 
    (...args) => 
      ^^^^ why are these the parameters to handler, and not catchAsync?
        handler(...args).catch(args[2]);
```

In the first returned function, it says:

```
    (...args: [Request, Response, NextFunction]) =>
```

Now, to my knowledge, ...args would be exactly one thing: 'handler' It wouldn't be the parameters to the callback because those aren't the arguments to catchAsync, they are the arguments to the callback function 'handler'. Is there something I didn't learn about arguments of a callback being passed to the original function?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you currently call this function? What's are the expected and actual outputs?

Comment: are you sure that this is not typescript code?

Comment: Okay, I edited out the type information to just show the JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catchAsync` is a function which returns another function. The outer function and the inner function each get passed different things. You would use this code something like the following:

```
const handlerWithCatch = catchAsync(someHandlerFn);
handlerWithCatch(someRequest, someResponse, someNextFn);

// Or on a single line:
catchAsync(someHandlerFn)(someRequest, someResponse, someNextFn)
```

On the insider `handler` will contain `someHandlerFn`, and `args` will be an array of `[someRequest, someResponse, someNextFn]`

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'm getting close, still trying to wrap my head around this

Answer (score 1):

Just re-read your question 1000 times.

As you mention `...args` is not the argument of catchAsync. This function is how you implement the Strategy design pattern in Javascript.

catchAsync itself will return a function that you will call with req,res,next

```
catchAsync(handler)(req,res,next);
```